# Scrapy Hanging on CSV Parse

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I've looked quite a bit for a solution to this and maybe it's just an error on my end.

I'm using the python/scrapy framework to scrape a couple of sites.  The sites provide me with .CSV files for their datasets.  So instead of parsing the gridview they provide line by line, I've set scrapy to download the .CSV file, then open the CSV file and write each value as a Scrapy item.

I've got my concurrent requests set to 1.  I figured this would stop Scrapy from parsing the next request in the list until it was finished adding all the items.  Unfortunately, the bigger the .CSV file, the longer Scrapy takes to parse the rows and import them as items.  It will usually do about half of a 500kb CSV file before it makes the next request.

```
     logfiles = sorted([ f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('QuickSearch')])
     logfiles = str(logfiles).replace("['", "").replace("']", "")
     ##look for downloaded CSV to open
     try:
        with open(logfiles, 'rU') as f: ##open
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
               item['state'] = 'Florida'
               item['county'] = county ##variable set from response.url
               item['saleDate'] = row[0]
               item['caseNumber'] = row[2]
               ..
               yield item
     except:
        pass
     f.close()
     print ">>>>>>>>>>>F CLOSED"
     os.remove(logfiles)
```

I need Scrapy to completely finish importing all the CSV values as items before moving on to the next request.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you post your spider code? If concurrent requests is set to 1, and your CSV parsing code is in the spider, you should have the wanted behaviour. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pault. Here's the spider code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30615/scrapy-very-procedural-better-alternatives

Comment: You can't find out what's wrong when your code ignores all exceptions.

Comment: @Changaco When I remove the try it processes as normal but with the same problem.  The issue is not the code that's processing, it's that scrapy calls the next request while it's parsing the CSV file. It will eventually change the county variable because the next request was called. I set all the concurrency settings to 1.  I don't understand how it will parse 100 or less items and then make the next request. The CSV files have on average 500-3000 rows each.

Comment: After further testing I've produced a work-around for my code by writing the county to the file before parsing.  I've seen similar issues with Scrapy holding a large amount of items in memory.  At the end of the scrape it will use upwards of 700mb of ram and output 30,000 or so items in about a minute.  Hopefully someone will be able to uncover this issue.